# What happens when a Rh+ mother pregnant with Rh- baby?

Tags: obstetrics, blood-type

I know that when a Rh- mother pregnant with Rh+ baby there might be a complication during the pregnancy, if the mother is sensitized to Rh+.

However, I have not found out any resource that states **what happens when the reverse is true, the mother is Rh+ and the child is Rh-?**

Is there any risk?